# how to div.width css property using js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have code like this :

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="container">
  ....
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:  #efefef;
}
```

JS:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var pageWidth = parseInt(myDiv.style.width);
```

I want to read css property and I can change value using js.
I have tried search with google, and my js code from link of google.
After I check the problem with safari's web inspector, there is problem in that I give sign for js code.
Why is that wrong?

Comment: The `style` JavaScript property only knows about CSS specified in the element's `style` HTML property, *not* to CSS specified in a stylesheet provided through a `<style>` or `<link>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var width = parseInt($('#myDiv').width(), 10);
```

Comment: No need to parse a returned `Number` value, cause `.width()` will not return extra string characters. And when you use `parseInt` use it with a (in this case decimal `10`) radix value `parseInt(value, radix);`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$("#myDiv").css("width","yourWidthhere");
```

To get the width of an element, just use:

```
$("#yourElementId").width();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
alert($('yourdiv').width());
```

live demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dCmLB/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this :

```
$("#myDiv").css("width","100%");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the class property using this code.

> var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv"); var pageWidth =
>   parseInt(myDiv.style.width);

I am going with a jquery way, here is the sample code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div.container { width: 300px; height: 400px; border: solid 1px black; overflow: hidden; background:  #efefef;}
        </style>    
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body><div id="myDiv" class="container"> hi...</div></body>
</html>
```

Then you should able to get and set the width using the jquery methods:

> $("#myDiv").width(); //Get
>   $("#myDiv").width(500); //Set